# Ubuntu Connect To SSTP VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, sstp

Does anyone have any experience with connecting an Ubuntu 10.10 machine to a SSTP VPN server? I haven't found anything too great of information on how to do it.

Comment: A google search suggests that maybe this project might have, or might be working on having what you want.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be [sstp-client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client) can do it? And [here](https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp) is network-manager support for it.

There are now Ubuntu packages for recent distributions, so you should be able to add [the PPA for `eivnaes/network-manager-sstp`](http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu) and install the packages:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
...
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sstp-client
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-sstp-gnome # NM configuration GUI
```

Answer (score 1):

### Example

Here is an example of an entry in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto work
iface work inet ppp
    provider work
    options pty "sstpc vpn.example.com --ca-cert /path/to/example.com.ca.crt --nolaunchpppd" \
            plugin sstp-pppd-plugin.so sstp-sock /var/run/sstpc/sstpc-uds-sock \
            lock nodefaultroute noipdefault noauth user myusername \
            refuse-pap refuse-chap refuse-eap nobsdcomp nodeflate novj \
            nomultilink \
            persist maxfail 0 \
            debug logfd 2
    pre-up touch /etc/ppp/peers/work
```

### Usage

Then you just use `ifup work` and `ifdown work` to connect or disconnect.

### Installation

You'll need to compile the sstp-client and install it. This can be used by following the instructions on http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/ or building a deb package using these instructions:

```
apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev debhelper ppp-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev
mkdir sstp-client.build && cd sstp-client.build
wget -o sstp-client-1.0.10.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/sstp-client/1.0.10/sstp-client-1.0.10.tar.gz/download
tar xzvf sstp-client-1.0.10
cd sstp-client-1.0.10
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
cd ..
dpkg -i sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb \
        libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb \
        libsstp-client-dev_1.0.10-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
cd /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5 && ln -s ../2.4.6/sstp-pppd-plugin.so .
```

### Fix symlink

The pppd lib dir is hard-coded to use 2.4.6, and not the installed version, which is why the symlink is required. This is a bug in the debian build description for sstp-client.

### Typical connection timeout issue

If you use the pppd `pty` option (which the example uses) it is vital that the parameters `plugin sstp-pppd-plugin.so sstp-sock /var/run/sstpc/sstpc-uds-sock` are specified. If you don't specify these, you'll end up getting the famous *Connection aborted, reason not known* error after approximately 60 seconds, and the connection will not transmit packets.

### CA certificate requirement

You also must have the CA certificate for the Active Directory domain the Microsoft SSTP VPN server is part of in the local file `/path/to/example.com.ca.crt`. This can usually be found in the `CertEnroll` SMB share on one of the Domain Controllers. Export it as a Base64-encoded X509 certificate and rename as appropriate. Use `certtool -i <example.com.ca.crt` to verify you have the correct certificate with the correct information.